# Change object color with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'd like to have several color boxes and change color of a clicked box on mouse drag. Example with one box:

[image]

Problem is, I have no idea how to approach this. I tried obvious mousemove after mousedown but drag stops when I move outside my box.

Should I create a temporary transparent object and use it to detect drag? Or is there a better/easier solution? Just for reference, I'm using Vue.js for my app.

Comment: Can you show your mousemove attempt? I would imagine that could be tweaked to work relatively easilly. (E.g. using a containing element for the mousemove event)

Comment: using a transparent div is what i would do. You're not obliged to create/destroy it at each use, it can be already present in the page with `display: none;` and "shown" when needed

Comment: Thanks! I've tried with transparent div and yes, it seems quite easy to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So on the original div I put `@mousedown="$el.pressed = true" @mouseup="$el.pressed = false"` and I made another div with Vue.js `v-if` attribute that's shown if `el.pressed == true`:

```
<div 
    v-if="$el.pressed"
    @mouseup="$el.pressed = false"
    @mouseout="$el.pressed = false"
    @mousemove="colorCoordinate"
    class="transparentItem"> </div>
```

[image]

Thanks for suggestion, don't know why didn't I try this before asking.